# Input shape error with Keras - not sure what's going on?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

This code was given to us by a teacher, so it should work right off the bat. However, I can't get it to run.

```
K.image_data_format()

# fix random seed for reproducibility
seed = 7
numpy.random.seed(seed)
# load data
(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = cifar10.load_data()
# normalize inputs from 0-255 to 0.0-1.0
X_train = X_train.astype('float32')
X_test = X_test.astype('float32')
X_train = X_train / 255.0
X_test = X_test / 255.0
# one hot encode outputs
y_train = np_utils.to_categorical(y_train)
y_test = np_utils.to_categorical(y_test)
num_classes = y_test.shape[1]
# Create the model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=(3, 32, 32), padding='same', activation='relu', kernel_constraint=maxnorm(3)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_constraint=maxnorm(3)))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu', kernel_constraint=maxnorm(3)))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))
# Compile model
epochs = 25
lrate = 0.01
decay = lrate/epochs
sgd = SGD(lr=lrate, momentum=0.9, decay=decay, nesterov=False)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=sgd, metrics=['accuracy'])
print(model.summary())
# Fit the model
model.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_data=(X_test, y_test), epochs=epochs, batch_size=32)
# Final evaluation of the model
scores = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test, verbose=0)
print("Accuracy: %.2f%%" % (scores[1]*100))
```

I receive the following error:

```
    ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 32 but received input with shape [None, 32, 32, 3]
```

Just thrown off since no one else had this issue with the given code. I did have to change the first line from

```
K.set_image_dim_ordering('th')
```

to

```
K.image_data_format
```

as I was being told that set_image_dim_ordering was not a known function of Keras.backend

Any ideas here? Could my change has introduced this error?

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** If data is in `channel_last` format, then change input shape from `input_shape=(3, 32, 32)` to `input_shape=(32, 32, 3)` in,

```
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=(3, 32, 32), padding='same', activation='relu', kernel_constraint=maxnorm(3)))
```

---

I found reference to `set_image_dim_ordering` below for keras 1.2.2,

https://faroit.com/keras-docs/1.2.2/backend/

Here, it mentions,

> For 2D data (e.g. image), "tf" assumes (rows, cols, channels) while
> "th" assumes (channels, rows, cols).

Since you are receving input shape `[None, 32, 32, 3]` that means it is `tf` format of `(rows, cols, channels)`. So providing `th` means the input shapes mismatch. You were using `theano` backend with `th` instead of tensorflow.

I could not find any reference to `set_image_dim_ordering` or `image_dim_ordering` in latest `tf.keras` backend. Instead these below provide method for getting and setting 'channels_first' or 'channels_last' format.

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/backend/image_data_format

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/backend/set_image_data_format